# FadeOut Animation not working on a modified bootstrap carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-carousel

I am working with bootstrap carousel that works perfectly minus the fadeout of the current slide. The fadeout animation just disappears without the animation. This reveals the background until the new slide appears. [it gives the appearance of a flash]... How can I make the fadeout animation work with the new slide. [current slide-out while new slides in]

I am using [this snippet](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/qg3xR) on [this site](http://staging.younglivinggear.ohabash.vp-dev.com/)